# What's the name of the technology that instantly boots to Linux from within Windows?

Tags: linux, windows

I once had some package that you could run to instantly replace a running Windows instance with a running Linux instance. I'm not talking about virtualization or coLinux. I'm talking about the moral equivalent of hot-swapping out the Windows kernel and replacing it with a Linux kernel. It may have only worked on Win9x for all I can remember. But I haven't been able to think of the name or find it since I happened upon it many years ago.

Comment: Does such thing exist? Seriously? I'm curious to see how the kernel lives without its tools and libraries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're probably remembering [loadlin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loadlin)

Comment: +1 now you mention it I think _that's_ what some distribution I once tested used, not grub4dos...

Answer (score 1):

I think it's [GRUB4DOS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/grub4dos/) using Win9x's option to start DOS applications in compatibility mode